# Is there are way to view all openid-connect claims for a user in Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

There are some default claims defined by openid-connect specification (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims) and I would like to find the value for each of these claims, for a given user, in Keycloak. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you find this information for each user.
[image]

If yes, follow those steps.
You need two steps. first, get the "id_Token" and decode it by JWT.io

#1 Get an "id_token" by Postman.
[image]
Detail step is following this instruction #1 to #5.
[How to get roles from custom client in keycloak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64024469/how-to-get-roles-from-custom-client-in-keycloak/64073714#64073714)

#2 Decode it using jwt.io
Copy the id_token from #1's body section(blue background text only)
Paste it into JWT.io'ss encoded section.
[image]

These values should be matched in Keycloak UI.
[image]

Comment: I have been stuck for a day. This works. Thank you for your detailed instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://oidcdebugger.com/ to get claims
It's just an automation for getting token